# how to overcome building error when I'm using bcp to export boost thread?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread, boost-build

I'm using boost *bcp* tool to export *thread* library from boost. The layout of exported library is

```
- Jamroot
+ libs
  |----- + thread
           |----- + build
                    |----- - Jamfile.v2
+ boost
+ doc
```

Now when I run *bjam* in build library is getting me :

```
boostcpp.jam: No such file or directory
../../../Jamroot:138: in modules.load
rule boostcpp.set-version unknown in module Jamfile</Users/miladrezayee/Softwares/developer/boost_1_53_0/tmp1>
/Users/miladrezayee/Softwares/developer/boost_1_53_0/tools/build/v2/build/project.jam:317: in load-jamfile
/Users/miladrezayee/Softwares/developer/boost_1_53_0/tools/build/v2/build/project.jam:62: in load
/Users/miladrezayee/Softwares/developer/boost_1_53_0/tools/build/v2/build/project.jam:115: in load-parent
/Users/miladrezayee/Softwares/developer/boost_1_53_0/tools/build/v2/build/project.jam:430: in initialize
/Users/miladrezayee/Softwares/developer/boost_1_53_0/tools/build/v2/build/project.jam:308: in load-jamfile
/Users/miladrezayee/Softwares/developer/boost_1_53_0/tools/build/v2/build/project.jam:62: in load
/Users/miladrezayee/Softwares/developer/boost_1_53_0/tools/build/v2/build/project.jam:168: in project.find
/Users/miladrezayee/Softwares/developer/boost_1_53_0/tools/build/v2/build-system.jam:570: in load
```

I exported *system* libray and when I run *bjam in build folder, it compiles successfully. I don't why *thread* library can't compile? Anybody have any idea what is going wrong with *thread* library?

Comment: Ok, I found the solution you should *bcp* like the following

    $ bcp build /path/of/exported/thread
    $ bcp chrono /path/of/exported/thread

Now I can run bjam on root path of exported *thread* library and it's compiling successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution you should bcp like the following

```
$ bcp build /path/of/exported/thread 
$ bcp chrono /path/of/exported/thread
```

Now I can run bjam on root path of exported thread library and it's compiling successfully.